# Generating a new matrix from an old one by an algebraic relationship

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, linear-algebra

I am trying to work a program using Mathematica to have a new matrix by applying an algebraic formula to the old matrix.

I do not know how this process is done using Mathematica and what are the appropriate functions. I will give a simple example explaining the mathematical process if it can help me write the program.
For example, consider a matrix M of size $(m\times m)=(3\times 3)$

```
M = 
  MatrixForm[{{Subscript[a, 11], Subscript[a, 12], Subscript[a, 
       13]}, {Subscript[a, 21], Subscript[a, 22], Subscript[a, 
       23]}, {Subscript[a, 31], Subscript[a, 32], Subscript[a, 33]}}]
```

[image]

I want to create a new matrix based on this algebraic equation 
$$a'_{ij}=a_{ij}+a_{i2}a_{2j}$$ where $i\neq j$ , if $i=j$ type only $a'_{ij}=a_{ij}$

The size of new matrix will be $(m-1 \times m-1)$ , N is a new matrix of M size $2\times 2$ such that

```
NN =
 MatrixForm[{{Subscript[a, 11], 
       Subscript[a,13] + Subscript[a,12] Subscript[a, 23]}, {Subscript[
        a,31] + Subscript[a,32] Subscript[a, 21], Subscript[a,33]}}]
```

[image]

steps,

1- Apply the algebraic equation to the matrix M or as follows
$$a'_{11}=a_{11} $$ $$a'_{12}=a_{13} + a_{12} a_{23} $$  $$a'_{21}=a_{31} + a_{32} a_{21}$$  $$ a'_{22} = a_{33} $$
2-Arrange outputs as a new matrix N MatrixForm

Comment: @kglr Thanks so much for the help I'm grateful to you. 
I have another question if you can help

Comment: Maybe to make life a bit easier: `(m = Array[Subscript[a, ##] &, {3, 3}]) // MatrixForm`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
With[{inds = DeleteCases[Range@Length@M, 2]},
 Table[M[[i, j]] + If[i != j, 1, 0] M[[i, 2]] M[[2, j]],
  {i, inds}, {j, inds}]
 ]
% // MatrixForm
```

Note that [`N`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html) is a built-in symbol, so you should avoid using it (and, to be safe, you might want to avoid using single-letter capital variable names in general).  A safe alternative is to use `NN` instead.

Comment: Another reason to only use lowercase stuff is that the autocomplete feature becomes so much more useful :)

Comment: @jjc385 When the execution shows some errors and do not get the result

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer I am a Master student in mathematics, but I have no experience in Mathematica. 
  I need some small programs Can you help me ...
  I do not have time to learn. 
with thanks and respect

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `Table[]` to generate the matrix entry-wise, one can do this by directly manipulating the original matrix.

I'll use a bigger example to illustrate:

```
mm = Array[C, {5, 5}];
```

Then,

```
With[{k = 2}, 
     Drop[mm, {k}, {k}] +
     (# - DiagonalMatrix[Diagonal[#]]) &[Delete[mm[[All, k]], k] ~KroneckerProduct~
                                         Delete[mm[[k]], k]]]
{{C[1, 1], C[1, 3] + C[1, 2] C[2, 3], C[1, 4] + C[1, 2] C[2, 4], C[1, 5] + C[1, 2] C[2, 5]},
 {C[3, 1] + C[2, 1] C[3, 2], C[3, 3], C[2, 4] C[3, 2] + C[3, 4], C[2, 5] C[3, 2] + C[3, 5]},
 {C[4, 1] + C[2, 1] C[4, 2], C[2, 3] C[4, 2] + C[4, 3], C[4, 4], C[2, 5] C[4, 2] + C[4, 5]},
 {C[5, 1] + C[2, 1] C[5, 2], C[2, 3] C[5, 2] + C[5, 3], C[2, 4] C[5, 2] + C[5, 4], C[5, 5]}}
```

An advantage of this approach is if the original matrix is a packed array, the result of this operation is also packed.